# Is it possible to chose not user, but application data using Google Picker Api?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, drive, google-picker

I need to let user access documents stored on my account(app is registered on it) Drive. I know how to access user Drive data with Picker API, but is it possible to access Application data using Picker API?

The point is - I have website, and I want to embed documents from Drive to my App, so users can collaborate on it. I store those on my Drive, and want users to have possibility select those docs, using Picker API(which will return `Document.EMBEDDABLE_URL`, that I latter embed in `<iframe>`to view and edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all. 'Application Data' is designed for things such as settings and configuration data that an app has per user, but a user should not see. If you wanted to do something like this you'd need to write your own Picker dialog and make sure the correct permissions are granted.

Comment: to be honest, I do not get what 'Application Data'  is. I thought it to be Drive of account, where App is registered. Can I store docs in App Data and share it?

Comment: It is a hidden area so Apps can store things such as user preferences, etc. It is explicitly designed to not be have individual files user visible. You cannot share documents from App Data. Everything you are asking to do has to be done from your regular Google Drive root folder (or folders in side it), not App Data.

Comment: I see, thanks. So to implement functionality I wrote, I need to have one main account, where I will store my docs on Drive, and write my own document manager ( picker ), to retrieve them, right? So I will need to install my Google App on that account, in order to have all needed permissions?